# Justification of the fixed variational distribution in diffusion models

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, latent-variable, variational-inference, diffusion

Diffusion models can be regarded as latent variable models ([Ho *et al.*, 2020](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf); Section 2), with the latents being an hierarchical chain of random variables $z_T → \dots → z_t → z_{t-1} → \dots → z_1$ (finally, from $z_1$ we sample the observation $x$). Under this view the diffusion process (the noise-adding steps, $\dots ← z_t ← z_{t-1} ← \cdots$) defines an approximate posterior distribution $q(z_{1:T}|x)$. However, this distribution is *fixed* (in contrast to typical latent variable models, such as variational autoencoders, which attempt to learn the approximate posterior). So I was wondering why does this approach work?

In my mind, a learnable and flexible variational distribution is essential in ensuring that the [evidence lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_lower_bound) (ELBO) is a tight lower-bound of the marginal log-likelihood $\log p(x)$ (for example in the EM algorithm, the E step closes the gap by setting $q(z|x)$ to $p(z|x)$). Otherwise, if the ELBO is loose do we have any guarantee that we maximize the true marginal log-likelihood $\log p(x)$?

Comment: I have the same question. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @Newton I'm not completely sure I fully grasp this yet, but my current understanding is that the ELBO can be made tight also by updating the parameters of the model (and not only through $q$): if the model is flexible enough, we can find $\theta$ such that $\mathrm{KL}(q(z|x)||p(z|x; \theta)) = 0$, so the bound will be tight. What I still don't get is why the bound is tight in the region of interest, that is, at the maximum of the ELBO (as I've tried to draw in [this figure](https://ibb.co/smjM6Hn)).

Comment: In case it's helpful, here is what Jascha Sohl-Dickstein said (personal communication): "[T]e variational bound can be made tight by either changing p to match q, or by changing q to match p. In a VAE both are done at once. In a (vanilla) diffusion model, only the second is done -- but this is still sufficient to bring the variational bound to 0 if the generative model is flexible enough, or has a structure which is closely enough matched to that of the inference model."

And [here](https://twitter.com/SimonPrinceAI/status/1618223898503544832) is Simon Prince's answer.

Comment: Why would $D_\text{KL}[q(z|x) || p(z|x; \theta)]$ become close to zero just because it can? Unlike in a VAE where maximizing ELBO over $\phi$ implies minimizing KL, there is nothing in the diffusion loss function that encourages this.

Comment: I agree with you, @Newton! Please let me know if you find something more about this. This question has been nagging me for a long time. And I thought I had been missing something obvious, given that every textbook takes this formulation for granted. But at least now we are two :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Under this view the diffusion process (the noise-adding steps, $z_T\dots ←z_t←z_{t−1}←\dots z_1$) defines an approximate posterior distribution $q(z_{1:T}|x)$

This is the **forward trajectory**, but the generative process we are interested in is in the **reverse trajectory** $q(z_{t-1}|z_t)$ (the denoising trajectory), since we want to provide the model a random noise and the model will generate an image.

Since the true denoising distribution $q(z_{t-1}|z_t)$ is intractable, we want to learn the parameterization for $p_\theta(z_{t-1}|z_t)$, assuming it Gaussian for a small $\beta$.
$$p(z_{t-1}|z_t) = \mathcal{N}(z_{t-1};\mu_\theta(z_t),\Sigma_\theta(z_t))$$

[image]

It is shown empirically in [Ho et al., 2020](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) that setting $\Sigma_\theta(z_t) = \sigma^2\mathbb{I} = \beta_t \mathbb{I}$ works well, so we can train a neural network to predict just the mean.

To do so we want to minimize the log-likelihood
$$\mathbb{E}[-\log p_\theta(x_0)]$$

But since we cannot access $p_\theta(x_0)$ as we do for VAEs, we can obtain a simpler objective using the Jensen Inequality, finding an ELBO that is dependent on $q(z_{t-1}|z_t)$.

$$
\begin{split} \mathbb{E}[-\log p_\theta(x_0)] \leq {} \mathbb{E}_q & \bigl[ D_{KL}(q(z_T|z_0) || p(z_T)) \\ & +  \sum_{t\geq 1} D_{KL}(q(z_{t-1}|z_t, x) || p_\theta(z_{t-1}|z_t)) \\ & - \log p_\theta(x | z_1)  \bigr]
\end{split}
$$

Where KL is the Kullback-Leibler Divergence between the two distributions.

Notice that the reverse process becomes tractable when also conditioned on the real image $x$, which does not allow sampling starting from noise (our final objective)

Since we are minimizing this ELBO, by optimizing the parameters $\theta$ we are actually closing the gap between the two distributions $q(z_{t-1}|z_t)$ and our approximation with a NN $p_\theta(z_{t-1}|z_t)$.

- The first term does not depend on $\theta$ and can be ignored for optimization (We could learn $\beta_t$ though)
- The central term is the most important, where we actually close the gap
- The last term could improve the last diffusion step

All of this and the following computations are explained well in this [blog](https://theaisummer.com/diffusion-models/), and further mathematical explanation is also available [here](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dario! I guess my question boils to the following: What guarantee do we have that by maximizing the ELBO with a _fixed_ distribution $q$, we also improve the marginal log-likelihood $\log p_\theta(x)$? I'm pretty sure that we can come up with a distribution $q$ that will make the ELBO a poor lower bound and as such it will provide no information on the true marginal log-likelihood. So, what properties does $q$ have to satisfy to ensure a tight lower bound for all parameters $\theta$?

Comment: The distribution $q$ is the *true* denoising process, which is dependent on data. I think it is the other way around: we are getting $p\theta$ close to $q$. Tell me if this answers your question!

Comment: I sort of understand your point, but if the goal is to get $p_\theta$ close to (a fixed, true) $q$ then why do we care maximizing the log-likelihood? Note that $\log p_\theta(x)$ doesn't depend on $q$, so maximizing $\log p_\theta$ may yield in principle a completely different objective. I understand that we never get to optimize the true log likelihood (due to intractability), but then I feel that the story is somewhat backwards here. What do you think?

Comment: The maximization of log-likelihood (or the minimization of negative log-likelihood in our case) is the way we estimate the parameters of a statistical model, in a way that it gives high probability to the data points of the dataset used for training. Notice that the ELBO **does** depend on the reverse process $q$, and in fact we are learning $p_\theta$ to be closer to $q$ by using the ELBO as a proxy. The ELBO also depends on $q$, but in this case it becomes tractable because during training we can condition also on the original image $x$.

Comment: I have edited the original answer to include these comments, I hope it is more clear now

Comment: I think what I might have missed is that we can close the gap between the ELBO and $\log p(x)$ also by making $p$ close to $q$ (and not only by making $q$ close to $p$, which is the more typical approach). This is only possible under certain conditions (_e.g._, the generative model has to be very flexible; $p(z|x)$ and $q(z|x)$ have to have a similar functional form), but I think these hold for diffusion models. I guess a follow-up question would be: can we train other latent variable models (_e.g._, PPCA, GMM) using a fixed variational distribution $q$? If so, how should $q$ be chosen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142132/discussion-between-dario-cioni-and-dan-onea).